# Region group tool gives ERROR 999999?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, error-999999, error-010067

I have an issue with the tool "region group". 
When I run my model, it always fails because of the region group tools.

The error state this:

> ERROR 999999: Error executing function. The table was not found.
>   [VAT_BluespotRegions] A column was specified that does not exist. A
>   column was specified that does not exist. The table was not found.
>   [VAT_BluespotRegions] ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid
>   expression.  Failed to execute (Region Group (2)).

I am not sure what table it is looking for, and why I need that table.

My model looks like this.

[image]

Someone who has similar experince with "region group tool", and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Yes - and the error is still the same. But thanks for the advice

Comment: The output pathname is: %Output Workspace%\BluespotRegions

Comment: Where is %Output Workspace% pointing to? If IN_MEMORY try a local file geodatabase.

Comment: My output workspace is set to a gdb. 
It does not work outside. The error is the same.

Comment: Reduce your model until the error does not happen anymore, then add things back until it breaks. Reduce from the other side again, same process. Then you have a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that people can look at.

Comment: I have figured it out. As you can see in my model, I had connected the same z-limit to both fill values, so raster output would be zero.